# Not entering a password for a graphical root action

Tags: sudo

I have edited my `/etc/sudoers` to successfully stop myself from having to enter a password for sudo, but I still have to enter a password to do GUI-based things like opening Synaptic or clicking `Unlock` in the User Accounts app. Interestingly, I don't need a password to run `gksudo synaptic`.

Is there any way to not enter a password for graphical root actions?

Comment: How did you edit the `/etc/sudoers` file? Did you use the `visudo` to edit or did you just open it up in a text editor?

Comment: @maggotbrain `visudo`

Answer (score 0):

First edit the sudoers file using

```
sudo visudo
```

And enter the line in the file:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You have probably already done this to get the root privileges without password prompt. On my system this also means that gksu will not prompt for password, as it is using sudo for the root privilege escalation.

Check your gconf settings using the `gconf-editor` tool. Don't run it as root - use your regular user privileges. Look under the `/apps/gksu` configuration tree.
On my system, for my user account, the

- "prompt" checkbox is unchecked (value false), the
- "sudo-mode" one is checked (true), and the
- "display-no-pass-info" one is checked (true).

This forces gksu to use sudo mode, which should respect your sudoers settings.